# How can I model a very porous rock?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, displacement

Consider:

[image]

I have tried playing with the displace modifier and various texture, but I cannot seem to find the right combination.

Comment: Hello :). Displacement seems like a good approach. What's your current result? And have you tried nodes displacement?

Answer (score 17):

It looks like a noisy volume to mesh transformation might work for you.
Perhaps a modified "Swiss Cheese" geo_node setup (below) would work with a noisy displacement shader added. Best of luck :)
[image: Sorry, Author unknown.]

On second thought...
Here is a material nodes only answer:
[image: Nodes:]
It will take a pretty dense mesh:
[image: Vert count:]
But, It renders pretty quickly.
[image: Render:]

Answer (score 11):

You could:

- Subdivide a cube, sculpt it:

[image]

- Give it a *Displace* modifier with a *Cloud* as *Texture*:

[image]

- Add some fake displacement with 2 levels of bump noises:

[image]

- Select random faces, extrude along normals in order to dig some holes:

[image]

- Deform the whole shape with the *Proportional Editing* on:

[image]

- Work on the color to give it small grains, create a vertex paint mask in order to create an area with a different color:

[image]

- Etc...